# Can't start bitbake on ubuntu with python2

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying so start bitbake, yet it tells me there's a previews instance running, despite none is present:

```
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...
NOTE: Retrying server connection... (Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/mnt/d/yocto/******/poky/bitbake/lib/bb      /main.py", line 441, in setup_bitbake
server = bb.server.process.BitBakeServer(lock, sockname, configuration, featureset)
File "/mnt/d/yocto/****/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/server/process.py", line 385, in __init__
self.sock.bind(os.path.basename(sockname))
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported)
WARNING: /mnt/d/yocto/*****/poky/bitbake/lib/bb  /main.py:476: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=13,         family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>
logger.info("Retrying server connection... (%s)" %    traceback.format_exc())

NOTE: Reconnecting to bitbake server...
NOTE: Retrying server connection...
ERROR: Unable to connect to bitbake server, or start one
```

What's makes it even more weird is that there's no lock file. Is there someone who had similar issue? I'm running bitbake on 20.04, with Python 2 (It's an older yocto branch)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when not terminating a previous bitbake session cleanly. Try to spot the still running bitbake processes with `$ ps aux | grep bitbake` and kill the perpetrator(s).

Answer (score 0):

If the bitbake process did not terminate correctly, there might just be a dangling `bitbake.lock` file present.